# Multithreading in AWS

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a new user of AWS EC2 and I am going to deploy a mostly IO-bounded application on a linux-based EC2 m4.large instance. As far as I can read on AWS Instances sheet, available [here](http://m4.large), I have 2 vCPUs, which means I have two hyperthreads running on 1 physical CPU. Therefore, my question and my doubts deal with multithreading processing. According to me, the maximum number of threads I d be able to use should be 2, but i was wondering if there were any guidelines about multithreading computing on AWS instances. Basically, my application reads a big file (1.5+ GB) and then it needs to process its chunks. I was thinking of implementing either a producer-consumer pattern (1 thread reading and 1 processing) or using a map-like approach (every thread opens the file and seeks on its partition). I know that these two approaches may have different complexities but I am interested in performances, thus, I need to squeeze as much speed as possible!! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is IO bound, using multithreaded processing is likely to be of limited utility, since multithreading is primarily useful for optimizing computation rather than IO.  However, if you really want to get every last bit of speed, your best bet is to program it both ways and see which works better under your particular circumstances.